# Google indexes WordPress site pages as https:// instead of http://

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http, ssl, ssl-certificate

for my WordPress website ( http://www.huysmangroep.nl/ ) 
Google indexes some of the pages with the secure https protocol.

when you search in google with the following query "site:huysmangroep.nl inurl:https", those are the pages i am talking about.

When you click on any of the pages, you'll get an message "Your connection is not secure" or similar (depending on browser).

My sitemap ( at /sitemap_index.xml) 
has http:// as prefix.

**things i have tried already:**

- clear cache
- set canonical url's to http://
- resend sitemap in google search console
- rewrite in .htaccess file (RewriteEngine 301 to http version)
- rewrite code in functions.php

  ```
  add_action( 'template_redirect', 'bhww_ssl_template_redirect', 1 );

  function bhww_ssl_template_redirect() {

      if ( is_ssl() && ! is_admin() ) {

          if ( 0 === strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'http' ) ) {

              wp_redirect( preg_replace( '|^https://|', 'http://', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ), 301 );
              exit();

          } else {

              wp_redirect( 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 301 );
              exit();

          }

      }

  }
  ```

Maybe i am impatient (the website is only online for a few days) and i need to wait for google to regconize my site correctly, but when potential visitors are getting the "Your connection is not secure" error, they will most likely not continue.

**EDIT:**
It seems like the site does have an SSL certificate. When i check the certificate online i do get the following tip:

None of the common names in the certificate match the name that was entered (www.huysmangroep.nl). You may receive an error when accessing this site in a web browser. Learn more about "SSL Certificate Name Mismatch Error"

Comment: google wouldn't index something if it wasn't reachable. if you don't have SSL on your site, you should ask why google was able to index something that shouldn't exist.

Comment: search google for some one else linking to you with https

Comment: Okay, it seems like my site does have a certificate, see: https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=www.huysmangroep.nl could it be "SSL Certificate Name Mismatch Error" ?